# Flutter, how can I get user location only once the application started?

Tags: flutter, location

I am currently trying to get user location one time at the start and focus the camera on that location just for one time, then I want it to stop but couldn't manage to do so. The code part is below.

```
bool element = true;
void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController _cntrl){
    setState(() {
      _ifEnabled();
      _ifPermissioned();
      _getLocation();
      _controller = _cntrl;
        _location.onLocationChanged.listen((l){
        _controller.animateCamera(
          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
            CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(l.latitude,l.longitude),
              zoom: 15
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
      _location.onLocationChanged.skipWhile((element) => false);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation on https://pub.dev/packages/location

```
onLocationChanged
```

listens the location and automatically updates when the location changes, so what you should use

```
getLocation()
```

> getLocation()
>   Allow to get a one time position of the user. It will try to request permission if not granted yet and will throw a PERMISSION_DENIED error code if permission still not granted.